# How to have android app add/change functionality of KeyDown/Up events, even when not active?

Tags: java, android, keyboard-events

I am developing an app 'A'.

Basically, say I want to add sounds to all key-up/down events, whenever I have turned on a switch A's UI.

The sounds from keystrokes should persist even after closing A, and using other apps (like messaging apps), and only should be turned off if one again opens A and turns off the switch.

In this way the app functions a bit like an extended settings-app. Even though this is not my final goal, any help in achieving the above would be much appreciated.

cheers

Comment: What you are describing -- monitoring all text input by the user -- is called spyware. Fortunately, that is not possible by ordinary apps. You are welcome to look into implementing an accessibility service, but you probably should talk to an attorney first.

Comment: @CommonsWare I see! Though I will say that this was not my purpose at all

Comment: In fact an accessibility service is more or less what I have in mind, so thanks for pointing me to this

Comment: Implementing an accessibility service for the purposes of improving accessibility is great! Note that the Play Store and other app distribution channels are cracking down on distributing accessibility services that do not improve accessibility.